# Drop down menu not clearing properly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm trying to build a very simple drop down menu. I want all of the li's to be 60px tall. I've used a few different tutorials for drop down menus but I keep running into the same problem. I can't get 'Link 1' to completely clear 'Drop 1'. It will clear the anchor but not the li itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZFWBU/12/

```
    <nav>

    <ul id="nav">

        <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

</nav>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color: #333;
}

nav {
    width: 992px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    background: red;
}

#nav {
    width: 992px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 100%;

}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}


/* main level link */
#nav a {
    width: 280px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e7e5e5;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding:  16px 20px;
    margin: 0;

    border: 1px solid white;
}

/* main level link hover */
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
    background: blue;
}

/* level 2 list */
#nav ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;

    background: #f5f5f5;
}

/* dropdown */
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav ul a {
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* clearfix */
#nav:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] #nav {
    display: block;
}

* html #nav {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already setting the `top` property in this declaration, I adjusted it to `50px` which you can [see on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XupQ/).

```
/* level 2 list */
#nav ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

As mentioned by pzin in the comments, you can reduce future problems by using `top: 100%`, which won't then need to be edited in the future when you change the sizes.

Comment: Regardless of which answer you marked as accepted, I recommend to use `top:100%` because it would be easier to handle with it and your submenu will always start at the bottom of the `li` element.

Comment: +1 to @pzin on using 100% - it gives you one less value to edit when you change your sizes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Update the following style and add `margin-top:15px;`

```
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be set the top position to the full height of the `li` element, so you don't will need edit it later if you change it someday because it will fit itself automatically:

```
#nav ul {
  top: 100%;
  [...]
}
```